# How to use class from a different project in C++ with Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

There's this class MailHandler in the solution MailTest, which I use to send signals to the class MailCom in the solution MailResponse. My problem revolves around creating an object of the MailHandler class in the MailCom class, which is in a different project, and doing operations from here. What is the most efficient way of establishing the connection without modifying the MailTest project into a lib or DLL?

I need to link with a correct path, but I'm not sure at which settings are important in this case. This is the current error I'm getting when trying to instantiate the MailHandler object:

```
1>     Creating library ..\..\bin\pvc6d.lib and object ..\..\bin\pvc6d.exp
1>CMailCom.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class QStringList __thiscall MailHandler::ReturnAllFunctions(void)" (?ReturnAllFunctions@MailHandler@@QAE?AVQStringList@@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall pvc::hardwarecom::CMailCom::CMailCom(class pvc::data::CData &,class pvc::data::CRudderServo *,class pvc::data::CPropulsionManager *,class QGraphicsScene *)" (??0CMailCom@hardwarecom@pvc@@QAE@AAVCData@data@2@PAVCRudderServo@42@PAVCPropulsionManager@42@PAVQGraphicsScene@@@Z)
1>CMailCom.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall MailHandler::MailHandler(class QObject *)" (??0MailHandler@@QAE@PAVQObject@@@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall pvc::hardwarecom::CMailCom::CMailCom(class pvc::data::CData &,class pvc::data::CRudderServo *,class pvc::data::CPropulsionManager *,class QGraphicsScene *)" (??0CMailCom@hardwarecom@pvc@@QAE@AAVCData@data@2@PAVCRudderServo@42@PAVCPropulsionManager@42@PAVQGraphicsScene@@@Z)
1>..\..\bin\pvc6d.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a class of a external project, you can try to #include its header file (MailHandler.h, MailHandler.hxx etc.). I assume thats what you did. Obviously there is also a according source file (MailHandler.cpp, MailHandler.cxx). You can try to add this file to your current project. If you are lucky it compiles and links and your unresolved externals go away. More likely the source file has other dependencies and does not compile/link right away.

This is rather a hack - not a robust long term solution. 
It's better to copy the file with its dependencies into your project
It's best to extract the needed classes in a separate project (i.e creating a lib or dll) that your project and that the other solution 'MailTest' are using as a independent client.

Comment: Thing is, the MailHandler class is using a separate class with an hardware connection and runs SDL, and SDL and Qt can interfere. This is why the files should run in different projects with the SDL functionality running its own thread.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the correct libraries. The linker does not know about the functions called, add `LIBS += -Lpath/to/lib -lthelib` to your pro file.